# Django -does apps in django called as micro services?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, microservices

I'm just learning about microservices and just want to know does django have inbuild microservices ? or the apps/modules which we have inside the django project is said to be microservices?

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5nSJ.png) I have attached project structure where I have more than 4 apps/modules(basket,payments,store,orders) were there. Is these apps are microservices in django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each services in MSA usually have their own databases. If your 4 of apps/modules share same database, then their dependencies are strong and it can be said as monlithic architecture(with such as foreign key relation constraint in django model).

Comment: u mean that if i create 4 different django project which will share with 4 database then it said to be microservices isn't it? what am I asking is apps inside the django suppose to be microservices if it shares with different databases right?

Comment: For the first question, yes. Because eash services are enforced to communicate outside channel each other in that case, which means that they are seperated.  However, if several apps are inside the same project, each apps communicate each other inside the project, then they are tightly coupled, and cannot seperated. Even though they share the same database, it can be said micro services. Each services are designed to be gathered up with same contexts, communicating each other through their aggregate root.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. As u said even it can  share same database right inside the same project like 4 or 5 apps use the same db which are connecting between using api right? can we design microservices  this way as well?

Comment: Yes, it depends on the intended design. As you know, database consists of tables, documents so on and so forth, and they can be partitoned too. If you just set rules that each apps have their own tables and dont use database layers constraints, and to some how achieve their commuication like using fasade pattern, then it can grow to microsercices anytime, whenever they are needed. The important point is whether their services are designed tightly coupled, placed inside same contexts communicating each other throguh their aggregate root or not. Details are actually implementation matters.